# Get column length of mysql table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get each column's name, type and length of mysql table.

```
SELECT column_name, data_type, column_type
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = "test_table"
```

It returns for example:

```
column1
int
int(11)

column2
varchar
varchar(255)
```

How do I get the column's length properly? I expect something like this:

```
column1
int
11

column2
varchar
255
```

I would need to trim the returned string from `column_type` to receive this `11` length. Is there no other way? I also found `character_maximum_length` but it gives different results (I guess in bytes).

Answer (score 1):

For max length in characters, use: `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH`

For max length in bytes, use: `CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH`

---

The query should look like:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = "test_table"
```

---

If the value is `-1`, it's a `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)` field.

A `null` value is a number that doesn't have a length.